# Odoo Python : How to copy/forward a phone number into user's device ( like <href="tel:"> behaviour) using Odoo python backend?

Tags: python, html, odoo, tel

Suppose in Odoo Form, i have a button. This button will trigger a python method in odoo backend to search the PIC and then forward/copy the PIC's `phone_number` to user's device, so that user can make a phonecall to the `PIC` using their device.

> The concern is, PIC is changing overtime. I mean, the pic will be
> based on shift schedule. So, if i attached the PIC or Phone Number in
> the Form View, it will gives the problem : the user will open the form view,
> taking time to view the data, scrolling for a moment, and then click
> to call the pic on another minute, but now the pic maybe different. Thats why
> i need to implement it in python way.

Its like the **`<href="tel:">`** in **`html`**, but i need to search the `phone_number` first.

```
def search_n_call_pic(self, input):
    # search the responsible_pic
    pic_object = self.search_pic(input)
    
    # get the pic's phone number
    pic_phone_number = pic_object.phone
    
    self.forward_this_phone_number_to_user_device(pic_phone_number)
```

i need to implement this method **"`forward_this_phone_number_to_user_device`"** so that it has the same behaviour like using html:

```
<a href="tel:pic_phone_number">pic_phone_number</a>
```

but i have to implement it in **`python`**.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: You can't run python in the browser. If you're talking about a python backend, please be more specific about your setup here.

Comment: @michjnich yes, i mean, i need to implement it on python backend sir.

Comment: `input` shadows the `input()` built in.

Comment: OK, so what kind of backend do you have? Are you using a framework here? Flask, Django, something else? If your button is triggering something in python, you have a python server running somewhere to handle that request - what is that server?

Comment: @PatrickArtner can you elaborate it? i still dont understand

Comment: @michjnich i use odoo

Comment: OK, I know zero about odoo, and whether you can even plug python into it like that. Suggest you make it clearer in the question what this is actually about, and maybe mention Odoo in the title. Might attract the right people ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the `pic_phone_number` field on `res.users` model. And you want to show a `tel:` URI on model `crm.lead`.

First you have to create a new computed field on model `crm.lead`:

```py
pic_phone_number_uri = fields.Char(compute="_compute_pic_phone_number_uri")

def _compute_pic_phone_number_uri(self):
    user_phone = self.env.user.pic_phone_number
    user_uri = "tel:{}".format(user_phone)
    for record in self:
        record.pic_phone_number_uri = user_uri
```

Now just add this field into the form view with widget `url`.

```xml
<field name="pic_phone_number_uri" widget="url" readonly="1" />
```

If you're on Odoo 13 or later you can use the `phone` widget and can skip adding `tel:` in the computation:

```xml
<field name="pic_phone_number_uri" widget="phone" readonly="1" />
```

Comment: its really a nice idea! 
but, in this case, the pic is changing overtime, the pic based on shift schedule. 
so, if user open the form view, taking time to view the data, scrolling for a moment, and then click to call the pic on another minute, the pic maybe different. thats why i need to implement it in python way..

Comment: Ah okay that's a very important information you should add into your question.

Comment: noted, i'll add it in the question.. thx!